# International phone number widget doesn't appear even though it was loaded successfully?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, django, intl-tel-input

I have a Django app where I want to use the intl-tel-input widget. in the console it shows that it was loaded successfully and when I inspect the page the input tag looks like this :

```
<input type="tel" name="Telephone_no" id="phone" class="textinput textInput form-control">
```

and the in the css file I changed the place to load images successfully like this `../images/` ( the place of the flags.png) and in the pagess I inserted this :

```
<script>
  var input = document.querySelector("#phone");
  window.intlTelInput(input);
 </script>
```

but the widget never shows up. what can I do?

Comment: Where is your script tag located? Have you tried running the above in the Browser  console?

Comment: I tried now and it returned `window.intlTelInput is not a function`

Comment: Looks like `intlTelInput.js` is not being loaded correctly. Have you loaded it and can you see it loaded in the sources/network tab in dev tools?

Comment: it is loaded successfully in both the debugging console and the network tab

Comment: Can you try `intlTelInput(input)` without `window`?

Comment: but i can't see the images flags and flags@2 being loaded.

Comment: I get not defined error.

Comment: I changed the js file to another and it worked. the only problem that it doesn't load unless i typed the functions in the console.

Comment: Make sure that your script that initialises the widget is either at the bottom of your HTML or called after the page is loaded. It may be being called before the page (and your input) is loaded

Comment: no, it's at the bottom with another script tag for another widget and the other widget is working.

Comment: I tried `$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#phone').intlTelInput();
});` and still the same problem/

Comment: `intlTelInput` is not a method on a jQuery element, you need to use `intlTelInput($('#phone').get(0))` if you really want to use jQuery to select the element. Or just follow the example from the docs

Comment: the problem is the docs method isn't working.